# How to have a better view on both mobile and desktop with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap 5 website template where I want to display divs in these order:

Desktop

[image: desktop]

Mobile

[image: Mobile]

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-2 pb-5 border-bottom border-3 border-light mb-3">
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Could you please help me with how to achieve it? I've tried to use several bootstrap classes, or even hardcode float left and right. Nothing helped. My code is above:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [flex direction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#direction).

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-2 pb-5 border-bottom border-3 border-light mb-3">
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-lg-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-lg-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-lg-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-lg-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-secondary">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ asset('icons/cash-on-delivery.svg') }}" alt="">
            <p class="ms-lg-3 mb-0 small">امکان تحویل اکسپرس</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```